# Full array present in console, yet array.length = 0

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand why, when I assign the results from an axios call to a variable, console logging said variable will show the complete object, yet consoling its length returns zero.

As such, when I try to run a forEach on the results, there is no love to be had.

```
getNumberOfCollections() {
  let results = queries.getTable("Quality"); // imported function to grab an Airtable table.
  console.log(results); // full array, i.e. ['bing', 'bong', 'boom']
  console.log(results.length); // 0
  results.forEach((result) =>{ // no love });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(results.constructor.name)`?

Comment: it may possible, results toString method is overriden to print result. queries.getTable("Quality") may return result object, where to get data u need to call other method. Try console.dir(results) to print all keys and try. else debug on runtime.

Comment: Search for “cache busting”.

Comment: what is ```['bing', 'bong', 'boom']```, content of the ```Quality``` table or some junk? Also what is the implem of ```getTable```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite likely that when you console.log the array, the array is still empty.

```
console.log(results); // full array, i.e. ['bing', 'bong', 'boom']
console.log(results.length); // 0
```

when `console.log(results.length)` is run, it is doing the `console.log(0)` and that's why `0` is printed out.

When `console.log(results)` is run, it is *going* to print out the `results` array later. That array is populated later when `console.log()` finally runs. (so console.log is not synchronous -- it will print something out a little bit later on.)

You can try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

and you are likely to see an empty array, because `JSON.stringify(results)` immediately evaluates what it is and make it into a string **at that current time, not later**.

It looks like you are fetching some data.  The correct way usually is by a callback or a promise's fulfillment handler:

```
fetch(" some url here ")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

so you won't have the data until the callback or the "fulfillment handler" is invoked.  If you `console.log(results.length)` at that time, you should get the correct length. (and the data is there).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to need to refactor and try a different approach. I lack a deeper knowledge of JS. If `console.log` acts like an await, why does `console.log(results && results.length)` also return 0?

Comment: actually, in your code, if you change it to `console.log(JSON.stringify(results));`, do you actually see it printing out an empty array?  I was thinking, how can the `results` array get populated between the moment of `results = queries.getTable("Quality");` and the moment of `console.log(results);`  The function `console.log()` doesn't act like an `await`, I think... it acts like `setTimeout(() => console.log(...), n);` where `n` can be `0` or `33`... which I need to find out more.

Comment: `console.log(results && results.length)` prints out `0`, because the `&&` operator evaluates left operand and if falsy, return left operand, (and `results` is an object, and therefore is truthy), so the right operand is evaluated and returned. (see MDN: `Logical AND (&&) expr1 && expr2 If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr2; else, returns expr1.`)

Comment: If `results = queries.getTable("Quality");` gets back an empty array that will be populated, maybe it is not a good API... I am not sure. It should be like AJAX or jQuery or any promise, which is `doSomething().then(() => { ... })` or `doSomething.success(() => { ... })` that is, taking a callback function (or handler)